# jQuery variable saved as JavaScript var unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

In a script I had the following:

```
$('#image-slider').empty();
```

Which emptied the image slider element in my application.

I wanted to move from directly using ID references in my function so I declared some variables at the top of the script including:

```
var globals = [];
globals.markup = [];
globals.values = [];
globals.markup.image_slider = $('#image_slider');
```

However when I now call:

```
globals.markup.image_slider.empty();
```

The slider is **NOT** emptied.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:

A full example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var projects = <?= $json; ?>;
  var globals = [];
  globals.markup = [];
  globals.values = [];

  globals.markup.title = $('#title');
  globals.markup.image_slider = $('#image_slider');


  function load_project(f)
  {
      var potential = window.location.hash.substring(1);

      $.each(projects, function(i, project){

          if (project.permalink == potential)
          {
              // Manage stats and fields
              $('#title').text(project.title);
              $('#agency').text(project.agency);
              $('#description').text(project.description);
              $('#website_url').attr('href', project.website_url);

              // Manage images
              globals.markup.image_slider.empty();
    .....
```

Edit: I was an idiot. It was a simple typo. 
`image_slider` should have been `image-slider` .. my bad.

Comment: You'll need to show more code. You sure you're waiting for jQuery to load when you define those globals? You sure you're using the same instance of the object everywhere?

Comment: console.log(globals.markup.image_slider); Does it contain the dom element?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions?.. Or it silently executes and doesn't produce the outcome? Check image_slider.length to see if it actually found your element. That variable initialization script could be running before the element is created.

Comment: @Johan When I did that it produced: `[ ]` so it's empty? I can't work out why though

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pmNpY/ Your problem is elsewhere

Comment: @davin You're the voice of reason. it should have been $('#image-slider').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @davin correctly suggested, the code is fine, the problem is elsewhere. I had accidentally typed `image_slider` rather than `image-slider` as the div is id-ed in the markup.

Comment: Hah, fair enough :) Then try and remember in two days.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your variable initialization script runs before the element is created, hence the jquery collection that's assigned to globals.markup.image_slider is empty. You need to put that code into a DOMReady script:

```
$(function() { globals.markup.image_slider = $('#image_slider'); });
```

Update: from the code sample, it looks like you already did that. Try moving it even later - to "load" event ( $(window).bind("load", ...); ) - or check your logic to ensure that the element is rendered by the document and not dynamically created later in your "load_project" somewhere.

Comment: Does the new edit include the change you suggest? I should have stated that it was in a .ready() function in the question.

Comment: I think it might be the variable scope? Should I pass the variable to the function?

Comment: @Alexcoady From your code, it looks like the function is a closed over, so it can't be called without seeing the globals variable. Also, in that case you would've got an exception. (Unless your "empty()" call is inside a try-catch which hides that from you)